# Cleaning up a column based on spelling? Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I've got two very important, user entered, information columns in my data frame. They are mostly cleaned up except for one issue:  the spelling, and the way names are written differ. For example I have five entries for one name: "red rocks canyon", "redrcks", "redrock canyon", "red rocks canyons". This data set is too large for me to go through and clean this manually (2 million entries). Are there any strategies to clean these features up with code?

[image: Screen_shot_of_data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into doing [phonetic string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) here. The basic idea behind this approach is to obtain a phonetic encoding for each entered string, and then group spelling variations by their encoding. Then, you could choose the most frequent variation in each group to be the "correct" spelling.

There are several different variations on phonetic encoding, and a great package in Python for trying some of them out is [jellyfish](https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish). Here is an example of how to use it with the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) encoding:

```py
import jellyfish
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": [
        "red rocks canyon",
        "redrcks",
        "redrock canyon",
        "red rocks canyons",
        "bosque",
        "bosque escoces",
        "bosque escocs",
        "borland",
        "borlange"
    ]
})
data["soundex"] = data.name.apply(lambda x: jellyfish.soundex(x))
print(data.groupby("soundex").agg({"name": lambda x: ", ".join(x)}))
```

This prints:

```
                                                      name
soundex                                                   
B200                                                bosque
B222                         bosque escoces, bosque escocs
B645                                     borland, borlange
R362     red rocks canyon, redrcks, redrock canyon, red...
```

This definitely won't be perfect and you'll have to be careful as it might group things too aggressively, but I hope it gives you something to try!

Comment: A little late, but thank you! This worked very quickly and easily, however it was a bit too aggressive, I'm looking into using double metaphone to see if that produces better answers

Comment: Will be curious to know how that ends up working out for you. This is tricky especially without additional context/an external knowledge base. Maybe you have additional columns in your data that could provide some signal as to how these should be grouped? A hybrid approach where you use this as an intermediate preprocessing step before manually going through and correcting the larger groups could work too depending on how many unique values there are.

Comment: Hi Luke! So the results weren't great. They dropped the amount of groupings from 66,000 to just under 6,000 using soundex... and to around 12,000 using double metaphone. They were both super easy to use, and quick; however they were both too aggressive. That's an interesting thought to use a groupby method with a reference column to try to aid in these functions.

Comment: Ultimately, if I had more time I would be trying out some fuzzy wuzzy probability ratio techniques on the column.  However, with time constraints I ended up filtering out any names that occurred less than ten times to try to weed out any names that were misspelled(I'm curious what you think of this logic). Here is my notebook if you want to see it in action: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/195wcooDtT2XhfpRXREWmLovm8XZPNymy#scrollTo=yj3AGyVng7Po